# jquery mouse position in canvas, and live element in DOM?

Tags: jquery, canvas, mouse, live

My problem is I have a canvas of a colour spectrum and onclick it assigns the color clicked to various parts of the page. When the user clicks the canvas I get the position like so.

```
$('#colorPicker').click(function(e) {
var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
var canvas1 = colorPicker.getContext('2d');
var data = canvas1.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
var rgb = 'rgb(' + data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2] + ')';
$('a').css({color: rgb});
}).disableSelection();
```

Only problem being that my canvas is in a jquery accordion, so the canvas position changes when the accordion changes, making my co-ordinates for the click handler attached to the canvas out by quite alot.

I tried adding a live event to the click but that changed nothing, how can I get the correct coordinates for the pointer within the canvas, is there a live way of getting the x and y values??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the click position relative to the `<canvas>` (assuming `#colorPicker` is the `<canvas>`):

```
var x = e.offsetX,
    y = e.offsetY;
```

Comment: I need the position clicked on the canvas starting from top left of the canvas where top left would be 0, 0. Everthing works with this script but the position of the canvas is 'live'.

Comment: I think you need to post a jsfiddle so we can see an example of the relevant code you're working with.  Most likely, you're listening for a click on the wrong element.

Comment: No I am not as it works is the canvas is static! And I can't js fiddle this is licensed

Comment: Are you handling the click that opens the selector, or the click on the canvas?  Perhaps you're listening for the wrong event.  Please at least post the code that wraps around the canvas.

Comment: It's ok I figured it out jquery offset doesn't work on hidden elements.

Comment: Not for `display: none` but yes for `visibility: hidden`